# PHP directory mirroring

Tags: php

I want to mirror a directory through php so i can the files without having to directly modify them.

I found this script ([here](http://lixlpixel.org/php_mirror/)) but i keep getting a 500 Internal Server Error when i try to set it up.

Could it be because its from 2004?

Are there any other ways to set this up or another method of doing this same thing?

here is some of the code i was using on a shared hosting plan

Agent file

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

set_time_limit(0);

function recur_dir($dir)
{
    $dirlist = opendir($dir);
    while ($file = readdir ($dirlist))
    {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && $file != '.DS_Store' && $file != 'mirror_agent.php')
        {
            $newpath = $dir.'/'.$file;
            $permissions = substr(decoct(fileperms($newpath)),-4);
            if (is_dir($newpath))
            {
                echo '
dir|'.$newpath.'|'.$permissions;
                recur_dir($newpath);
            }else{
                echo '
file|'.$newpath.'|'.$permissions.'
'.bin2hex(file_get_contents($newpath));
           }
        }
    }
    closedir($dirlist); 
    return $mod_array;
}

header('Content-type text/plain');
echo 'mirror_agent here';
recur_dir('.');

unlink(__file__);

?>
```

Client File

```
<?php

$mirror_agent = 'http://moddline.com/safe/mirror_agent.php';

function hex2asc($temp)
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($temp); $i += 2) $data .= chr(hexdec(substr($temp,$i,2)));
    return $data;
}

function file_write($filename, $filecontent, $mode='wb')
{
    if($fp = fopen($filename,$mode))
    {
        fwrite($fp, $filecontent);
        fclose($fp);
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

error_reporting(0);

set_time_limit(0);

$cont = file_get_contents($mirror_agent);
$files = explode("\n",$cont);

if(trim($files[0]) == 'mirror_agent here' && is_writeable(dirname(__file__)))
{

    for($i = 1; $i < count($files); $i++)
    {
        if(trim($files[$i]) != '')
        {
            $parts = explode('|',trim($files[$i]));
            $permissions = intval($parts[2], 8);
            if($parts[0] == 'dir')
            {

                mkdir($parts[1],$permissions);
                $done[] = $permissions.'|'.$parts[1];
            }elseif($parts[0] == 'file')
            {
                file_write($parts[1], hex2asc($files[$i+1]));
                chmod($parts[1],$permissions);
                $done[] = $permissions.'|'.$parts[1];
                $i++;
            }
        }
    }
    // output status
    echo '
<pre>
following files were copied:';

    for($i = 0; $i < count($done); $i++)
    {
        echo '
'.$done[$i];
    }

    echo '
</pre>';

    unlink(__file__);
}else{
    echo '
<pre>
ERROR:
'.$mirror_agent.'
does not respond like a mirror_agent should or
the directory '.dirname(__file__).' is not writeable.
</pre>';
}

?>
```

Comment: cant u just use rsync? would be a far more secure, stable, safe method...

Comment: I could but isnt that only for servers that have ssh assess as well? I'm looking for a shared hosting alternative aswell

Comment: yes, rsync requires ssh on the target server. your script fails probably due to some security restrictions on your host. 
i personally would not put effort into a higher level solution like this but see to it that i can use proper methods.

Comment: Maybe you should turn on your error_reporting (Best at the beginning of your script, and check the PHP and Apache error log)

Also check the PHP configuration for the Open Basedir restriction
http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir